# Regex to pull out the string between 2 underscores

Tags: regex, preg-match

I have a pattern of type *anystring_OPCtarget_anystring*.
Can I get some help as how to verify if the string between the 2 underscores is of type `"OPC(target)"` and pull out the target using regex.

Suppose if my string is: `MP700000001_OPC32_812345643`
first, I need to verify if the string between underscores starts with `OPC` and then get the target text after `OPC` and before the 2nd underscore.

Help appreciated!!!

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^[^_]*_OPC\K[^_]+
```

And grab matched data.

- `^[^_]*_OPC` will match any text upto first `_` followed by `OPC`.
- `\K` will reset all previously matched data
- `[^_]+` will match data after `OPC` before 2nd `_`

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6VW5sd/3)

**Code:**

```
$str = 'MP700000001_OPC32_812345643';

preg_match('/^[^_]*_OPC\K[^_]+/', $str, $matches);

echo $matches[0] . "\n";
//=> 32
```

Answer (score 6):

```
_([^_]+)_
```

First capturegroup is text between the two underscores
Explanation:

```
_([^_]+)_
_                First underscore
 (     )         Capture group
  [^ ]           Everything but this character class
    _            No underscores
      +          One or more times
        _        Closing underscore
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the following approach to get the needed "target":

```
$str = 'MP700000001_OPC32_812345643';
$target = '';
if (preg_match('/^[^_]+_OPC(\w+)_\w*$/', $str, $matches)) {
    $target = $matches[1];
}

print_r($target);  // 32
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a language that supports lookahead and lookbehind you can do something like this:

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=_)OPC[0-9]+(?=_)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("MP700000001_OPC32_812345643");

    if (m.find()) {
        String target = m.group(0);
        System.out.println(target);
    }
```